# Pandas MultiIndex versus Panel

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas, what are the reasons to use a Panel versus a MultiIndex DataFrame?

I have personally found significant difference between the two in the ease of accessing different dimensions/levels, but that may just be my being more familiar with the interface for one versus the other. I assume there are more substantive differences, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my practice, the strongest, easiest-to-see difference is that a Panel needs to be homogeneous in every dimension. If you look at a Panel as a stack of Dataframes, you cannot create it by stacking Dataframes of different sizes or with different indexes/columns. You can  indeed handle more non-homogeneous type of data with multiindex.

So the first choice has to be made based on how your data is to be organized.

Comment: Ok, so relaxed homogeneity is one advantage of a MultiIndex over a Panel. Is there any disadvantage? For example, is it slower?

Answer (score 3):

Panel has been deprecated in pandas v0.20.1 (May 5, 2017) and will be removed in a future version. It is recommended to represent 3-D data with a MultiIndex on a DataFrame via the to_frame() or with the xarray package.

References:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-20-1-may-5-2017
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-panel